# insert <?php into a string in php file

Tags: php, javascript, string

i would like to create a JavaScript string that holds a dynamic php page 
for the

```
newwindow=window.open();
newdocument=newwindow.document;
newdocument.write(HTMLstring);
newdocument.close();
```

functions.
when i try to insert the first part of the page it starts a php block

```
    HTMLstring+='<?php';
    HTMLstring+='echo "this should print";';
    HTMLstring+='?>';
```

i have tried to start with

```
    HTMLstring+='<\?php';
```

but i get

```
    <!--?phpecho "this should print";?-->
```

is there a way to do this in JavaScript?

thank you

Comment: JavaScript is run client-side.  PHP is a server-side language.  This will not work.  What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how JavaScript and PHP work. PHP runs on the server, JavaScript runs in the client. Using JavaScript to create PHP code is fundamentally impossible.

In your case, it should be possible to use PHP to output the string into JavaScript directly (like

```
<script> var myHTML = "<? echo $variable; ?>"; </script>
```

the other common workaround for when you need to access PHP from within JavaScript is [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).